# What is causing this TypeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two different files, containing two different classes (Let's call them `Foo` and `Bar`).

In the file (`Foo.py`) with class `Foo`, I have:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):

    ...
```

And in the file (`Bar.py`) with class `Bar`, I have:

```
from Foo import Foo

class Bar(Foo.Foo):
    def __init__(self):

    ...
```

When I run my code, I get this `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bar.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Bar(Foo.Foo):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

Why is it telling me I have 4 arguments to pass `__init__` when the only argument I have in the code is `self`?

Comment: No, it is telling you that `__init__` __received__ 4 arguments when all it takes is 1 (`self`).

Comment: Ahh, but where are these arguments coming from? @iCodez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your problem is that you are importing the class directly, but then trying to access it via the module name.

If you have a class `Foo` inside a module source file `foo.py` then you can use it like this:

```
import foo
new_instance = foo.Foo()
```

You can also do this:

```
from foo import Foo
new_instance = Foo()
```

But you are trying to do this:

```
from Foo import Foo
new_instance = Foo.Foo()
```

In the expression `Foo.Foo()`, the first `Foo` is your class.  Then after the `.` Python parses out `Foo` and looks for a class member called `Foo`.

Note: I suggest you comply with PEP 8 guidelines, and your modules should use lower-case names.  Thus `foo.py` rather than `Foo.py`.

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I get `Foo instance has no __call__ method`

Comment: When you write `Foo()`, you are trying to call it like a function,which actually calls its `__call__()` method function.  If you don't have that function, the error does make sense.

Comment: I used this:

`import foo

new_instance = foo.Foo()`